# Why do my log-dirs and local-dirs keep getting filled up when running spark on yarn?

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

I am running `pyspark 1.6.1` on YARN, and I keep getting

```
Container marked as failed: container_1467098127754_0001_01_000024 on host: ip-23-4-2-123.ec2.internal. Exit status: -100. Diagnostics: Container released on a *lost* node
```

Which, as I understand it means that the node is running out of space.  and sure enough, when I run `df -h` on that node, I see that it is about 80% full.

So, I look at my `yarn-site.xml` file and look for `yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs` and `yarn.nodemanager.log-dirs` and I ssh into each of the nodes and delete the contents of those directories.  Then I see that `df -h` is very low, at like 14% which is good.  I rerun the job, and then the same error happens with the lost node.

How is it possible that these are getting filled up so fast?  And what can I do about it?  is it the number of partitions?  the logging level I'm using - what can it be?

thanx.

Comment: The logging level may have been set to `debug` that it has to log everything. You can change this to `error`. The best way to also manage log directory is to keep it away from the application home, by attaching a new volume for log

Comment: that is fine for the logs, but what about the temporary data stored in `yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs`?

Comment: I thknk that is usually more of a problem